# The role of Germany's economic growth in the outbreak of the Great War

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-history, germany, uk

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_by_past_GDP_(PPP)) Wikipedia article shows that UK's economy was bigger than Germany's economy until 1900, but after 1910, Germany's GDP overtook UK and it became the first European economy. Imperialism is considered as the main cause of WWI. I want to know if this economic race played a role in the outbreak of the First World War.

Comment: It's also worth considering the comparison between Germany and Russia, the latter economy approximated in the Wikipedia table as "Former USSR".

Comment: As far as economics as a science is concerned, I don't see how this q can be answered with anything other than opinion. "Does economic growth or competition lead to war" could marginally be on-topic and answered with maybe an econometric analysis (e.g. a logistic regression) across several instances of such events. Did it lead to war in one particular case is much a q of historical opinion, where by the way this q was also posted https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62521/what-was-the-role-of-germanys-economic-growth-in-the-outbreak-of-the-great-war and deleted because it didn't get UV

Comment: On the general aspect see https://pesd.princeton.edu/node/386 although it's alas a narrative and not an econometric treatment. Somewhat more data-based (review) https://www.unicef.org/socialpolicy/files/Economics_and_Violent_Conflict.pdf in particular the works of  Collier and Hoeffler reviewed there (p .4).

Comment: A more empirical analysis (albeit more limited in scope) https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0022002715613565